# Why does \033 escape work for vars like PS1 and \x1b doesn't?

Tags: bash

According to the documentation of `echo` builtin, (as well as `printf`), `\033` and `\x1b` should both translate to the same ASCII control code (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, which is decimal 27).

While both `\x1b` and `\033` work the same for simple `echo -e` commands, they cannot be interchangeably used in prompt variables, such as `PS1`. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there is no provision in Bash for interpreting them. As shown in the **PROMPTING** section of the `bash(1)` man page, only octal escapes are allowed for an arbitrary character.

As for *why* this omission exists, I can only surmise that it's for compatibility with POSIX sh, but you'll need to ask Chet Ramey himself as even version 4.12 of the Bash FAQ does not yet cover this topic.

Comment: True, the `bash` manpage covers it. So the set of escape sequences recognised by Bash prompt is completely independent from what `echo` uses.

Answer (score 0):

ASH Shell:

I can confirm that `\x1b` is interpreted correctly by the ASH Shell compiled with Busybox v1.33.1.

To add to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer, the reason BASH will still print hex escape patterns using your typical "print" utilities is because they are coded to handle these things. See the following man-page excerpts from each of the executables:

`echo -e '\x61'`

```
-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
\xHH   byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)
```

`printf '\x61\n'`

```
\xHH   byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)
```

`bash` just has

```
\e
  An escape character.
\nnn
  The character whose ASCII code is the octal value nnn.
```

---

Side Notes:

- I just happened to try it out on my iPad running the [iSH App](https://ish.app), which happens to run `/bin/ash -> /bin/busybox` as its default shell.